# Using the javascript function without repeating it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

The following `<div>` section I am duplicating and below the JavaScript function, I want to use again and again. Share your ideas if this is possible.

```
 <?php  $new_material = ["a","b","c"];   //array to pass in foreach 

           foreach ($new_material as $mat) {

     ?>

    <div class="row " id="row2">
              <div class="row " id="row2.1">
                <div class="col-xs-2"> 
                  <label>Material Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                  <label>Brand</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <label>Category</label>
                </div>
              </div>

                <div class="row " id="row2.2">
              <div class="col-xs-2">  


              <p id="material_select"><?=$mat?></p>


          </div>

                <div class="col-xs-3">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="brand" id="brand"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="category" id="category"/>
                </div>
                  <label class="col-xs-2">Total Quantity:</label>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="totalquantity" id="totalquantity"/>
                <br>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="row " id="row2.3">
                <label class="col-xs-1">Specification</label>
                <label class="col-xs-1">Quantity</label>
                <label class="col-xs-2">Unit</label>
               <button type="button" onclick="duplicate()" class="btn btn-info col-xs-3" >Add Specification</button>
                        <label class="col-xs-2">Unit:</label>
                        <span id="units_div">
                        <p class="" name="units"/>
                      </span>
              </div>
                  <div class="row " id="duplicater" >
                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                      <input type="text"  id="specification" class="form-control" name="specification[]"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                      <input type="text"  id="quantity" class="form-control" name="quantity[]"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2" id="units1_div">
                        <p id="unit" name="unit[]"/>
                      </div>  
                    <div class="col-xs-2" id="delete">
                      <button id="delete_btn"type="button" onClick="removeduplicate(this)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" style="visibility:hidden;">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>

                    <br>
                <div>
                <div class="row " id="row2.4">
                  <label class="col-xs-1">Tax</label>
                  <label class="col-xs-1">Tax%</label>
                  <label class="col-xs-2">Tax Amount</label>
                  <button type="button" onClick="duplicate1()" class="btn btn-info col-xs-3" >Add Tax</button>
                  <label class="col-xs-2">Rate</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rate" id="rate"/><br>
                  </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="row " id="duplicater1" >
                    <div>
                     <input type="text" id="taxamt" class="form-control" name="taxamount[]"/>                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1" id="tax_div">
                        <p id="unit" name="taxper[]"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-1">
                      <input type="text" id="taxamt" class="form-control" name="taxamount[]"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-2" id="delete">
                      <button id="delete_btn1" type="button" onClick="removeduplicate1(this)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" style="visibility:hidden;">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" id="row 2.5">
                  <div class="col-xs-7">
                  </div>
                    <label class="col-xs-2">Total Amount</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <p id="totalamount" name="totalamount"></p>
                    <input type="hidden" value="" name="totalamount" id="totalamount" readonly/><br>
                  </div>
                </div>

        <?php 
          }
          ?>
```

JavaScript code: This is the JavaScript function, I want use whenever I'm duplicating the above code as I'm passing the material name in `foreach()` loop, so it is duplicating based on every material name.

```
function duplicate() {
  document.getElementById('delete_btn').style.visibility = "visible";
  var original = document.getElementById('duplicater');
  var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "duplicetor" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
   document.getElementById('delete_btn').style.visibility = "hidden";
   document.getElementById('specification').value="";
   document.getElementById('quantity').value="";
   document.getElementById('unit').value="";
}

function removeduplicate(element){
    element=element.parentNode.parentNode;//gets the id of the parent
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question, it is very unclear what you are asking

Comment: now, are you able to understand?

Comment: no, all you have done is changed a few words in your title....you have not explained anything any differently. What exactly are you "duplicating" and how are you doing that? What is your javascript supposed to do, etc....

Comment: what is `<?php  foreach ($new_material as $mat) {  ?>` supposed to be doing exactly?

Comment: It is the part of code duplicating the html apparently, so he just have to load his js just before that since putting it in the head seems to not please him.

Comment: @LaurentFauvel  sure, I just dont see how that s going to work, the OP has `<?php  foreach ($new_material as $mat) {  ?>` ..... (note the missing "}") then a bunch of `html` with a few other `php` blocks mixed in followed by ` <?php  } ?>` apparently trying to close off the first code block. TO my knowledge, you cannot nest `php` blocks this way....

Comment: You can just echo the script at begining of php,something like <?php echo "<script..." ;  But i will not recommand it. He is not showing all his code there is obviously a head tag somewhere where he can just load his js.

Comment: @LaurentFauvel You're missing the point. The code the OP has provided is invalid......unless they are leaving out random chunks in the middle.....either way, my questions are perfectly valid

Comment: Nope his code will work, better practice is to use endforeach but } does work, it just make code painfull to maintain.

Comment: And nesting html in php blocks is common practice (specially in PHPTemplate).

Answer (score -1):

Natural place of javascript files/code loading is in the head so just place it there. Since you do not want your head to be duplicated anyways (invalid html).

Comment: Also style in html is a no no. Remove your style from your hr and put it in a css file or at worst in the head.

Comment: Can somebody help me out?

Comment: I gave you two solutions (js in head or js loaded before the foreach), both work, what do you want more?

Comment: Well show us how you implemented it because both method work, you might have done a mistake.